# replace multiple consecutive instances of a string with a single instance of a modified version of the old string

Tags: bash, sed

Let me specify exactly what I'm trying to do. A script I made generates XDoTool commands that draw an image. this is the typical command that moves the mouse right: `xdotool mousemove_relative --sync --polar 90 2`. The problem here is that if the mouse needs to be moved more than 2 pixels at once, it simply runs the above command as many times as it takes to move that distance, significantly increasing the time it takes to draw the image. instead of changing the distance parameter in the command (which is set to 2 by default). To handle this, I'd like for it to seek out multiple occurrences in a row of a line containing the command, and ONLY the command, with a single instance of the command, but with the amount of instances in a row of the above command, times two, set as the distance parameter.

**Keep in mind,** that consecutive instances of the above command are only to be replaced if they are the only contents of the line. For example:

```
xdotool mousemove_relative --sync --polar 90 2
xdotool mousemove_relative --sync --polar 90 2
```

would be replaced with:

```
xdotool mousemove_relative --sync --polar 90 4
```

but the following:

```
xdotool click 1; xdotool mousemove_relative --sync --polar 90 2
```

would not be replaced because there are other things in the line besides the command.

Comment: can you post more detailed input and expected result?

Comment: @AfterHours: I'm not one of the downvoters, but I think I can tell you what's wrong here: First, stackoverflow is not a code-writing service. You're essentially asking someone to write a complete script for you to spec. In general, people here are willing to help, but not to do your job for you. Second, this feels like the wrong solution. Why not just fix the first script so it does single big moves rather than a bunch of little moves? You're asking for a fix to clean up a problem that shouldn't exist in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/(xdotool m.*) 2\s+\1 2/\1 4/g;' old.txt  > new.txt
```

---

[image]

---

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fmplOg/3)